# How to get the jacobian of this change of variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, jacobian, change-of-variable

I am reading an article where we have
$$\iint_{S^2\times\mathbb{R}^3}f(w,v)\,dw\,dv$$
where $w\in S^2$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}^3$ are variable vectors. A change of variable was done $(w,v)\mapsto(p,q)$ where
$$p=(v\cdot w)w$$
and
$$q=v-p=v-(v\cdot w)w.$$

That is, $p$ is the projection of $v$ on $w$, and $q$ is the projection of $p$ on $w^\perp$, where $w^\perp$ is the rotation of $w$ in the plane $\{w,v\}$ by $\pi/2$. Then $p\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $q\in\{p\}^\perp$.

They computed the Jacobian to be $$\,dw\,dv=\frac{2}{p^2\sin(p,p+q)}\,dp\,dq.$$
Does anyone have an idea how to compute this Jacobian explicitly?

The article can be found [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00704952v2/document)

The part I am asking about is in page 12 proposition 5.

It has to be related to spherical coordinate, but since $\omega$ is a vector I don't understand how they compute the Jacobian.

Comment: It is not clear what coordinates you are choosing, and you need the know the choice of coordinate systems in order to compute the Jacobian "by hand". For the $w,v$ space, I'm guessing you use spherical coordinates for $w$, and usual Euclidean coordinates for $v$. But it's not clear what coordinates are being chosen for the $p,q$ space.

Comment: I will edit my question and add the article I’m reading. Actually I’m new to this subject and that’s why I didn’t figure out what the exact coordinates used are. I am very thankful for any help you can offer.

Comment: Does $\sin(p,\,p+q)$ mean the sine of the angle between $p,\,p+q$?

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the paper's notation. First, rearrange the claim as $dpdq=\tfrac12p^2\sin(\omega,\,V_\ast)d\omega dV_\ast$. We actually don't need a matrix of partial derivatives to prove this, any more than you need them to prove the more famous $dxdy=rdrd\theta$; in both cases, we can make a geometric argument, by comparing two coordinate systems' infinitesimal area elements.

In our example, the left-hand side is such an element. The right-hand side is half the area of an infinitesimal parallelogram with angle $(\omega,\,V_\ast)$ between sides of length $|p|d\omega,\,|p|dV_\ast$. Don't let this factor of $\tfrac12$ surprise you; it's a consequence of the degeneracy in $p=\pm|p|\omega$. The paper itself makes essentialy this argument, between Eqs. (36) & (37).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I think I lack some information concerning thinking geometrically about a change of variable in space. Do you have any idea about a good reference to learn about it?

Comment: @FareedAbiFarraj I can't find suitable references. I can only recommend you work with diagrams. For example, look at [this](https://sccn.ucsd.edu/~arno/ica/polar.gif), then again at the diagram above (36).

Comment: I was discussing with my supervisor about this jacobian and I gave him this significance, but he told me that this is not enough for a proof. A change of  
variable can be done only on open sets. Here we are working on $(p \in\{q\}^{\perp})$ which is a sub linear space of $\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3$; the Lebesgue  
measure is the induced measure; dpdq is not the Lebesgue measure of a  
subspace. Could you please help me have a formal reasoning for this Jacobian then?